# Regex to get specific numbers from string

Tags: android, regex, numbers

I have specific string like this

```
372591089, jni, oduction, to, A, hnr, android, -"The, mAt,352, 268, 638, 257, 65, JI, 0, 00, 0, 0, al, 31/07/2015, oHa, Jile, 786118029,
```

I want to extract specific sequence of numbers in this string `352, 268, 638, 257, 65`, I only know this sequence of digits can be 14 digit like example or 16 digit, this numbers changes every time not static numbers.

What is best way to extract it? any regex or specific way ? I can solve it by split - match than join but my string can be more than 1000 letter.
So can anyone suggest better way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*See Example*

***`(\d{3}\,\s\d{3}\,\s\d{3}\,\s\d{3}\,\s\d{2})`***

***https://regex101.com/r/Bilx53/3/***

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/nirkJh/1

you can try this regex 
(?:\s?\d+\s?,){4}\s?\d+